# How do I create this clustered column chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a data sheet split into three tables (one for each level). Within each table, there are four columns based on the answer (positive, neutral, negative, or N/A) and then there are six rows, each row representing a question. I want to create a clustered column chart for each question that has on the X axis each level and on the Y axis the percentage range (0-100). There should be a total of 12 columns. For example, the first clustered column chart would have four columns for level I being 91%, 9%, 0%, and 0%.

How do I create this using the chart wizard in Excel? I don't know what data to select for the data series.

**If you open Word 2003 and insert a chart it will show precisely what I'm looking for.**

```
Percentages - Green (Level I)               
    Positive    Neutral     Negative    N/A
Q1  91          9           0           0
Q2  91          9           0           0
Q3  91          9           0           0
Q4  86          14          0           0
Q5  95          5           0           0
Q6  86          9           0           5

Percentages - Green (Level I)               

    Positive    Neutral     Negative    N/A
Q1  100         0           0           0
Q2  80          16          4           0
Q3  96          4           0           0
Q4  92          4           0           4
Q5  88          8           0           4
Q6  88          12          0           0

Percentages - Green (Level I)               

    Positive    Neutral Negative    N/A
Q1  100         0                   0   
Q2  100         0                   0   
Q3  100         0                   0   
Q4  100         0                   0   
Q5  0           100                 0   
Q6  100         0                   0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could represent this as a clustered-stacked chart. Each block of data has its own cluster, with a space between, and each cluster has stacked data (pos, neutral, neg) for the six items Q1 through Q6.

This will take some hefty realignment of the data. I've written a tutorial that will help with this:

[Clustered and Stacked Column and Bar Charts](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/)